# making a progress bar update, depending on how many check boxes are ticked

Tags: c#, checkbox, progress-bar

I have almost completed this, but my progress bar is really not very good. I have a number of checkboxes. If a checkbox is checked then a set process will run. if the other check box is checked then another given process will run. below is an example of the code

```
if (pslist.Checked == true)
{
      progress = 9;
      backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(progress);
      string commandlineargs = "-f " + imagefile + " --profile=" + profile + " pslist" + " --output-file=" + output + @"\pslist.txt";
      Process process = new Process();
      ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
      startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
      startInfo.FileName = vollocation;
      startInfo.Arguments = commandlineargs;
      process.StartInfo = startInfo;
      process.Start();
      process.WaitForExit();
      process.Close();
}
```

for every check box in my form, there is code very similar to this with a few changes.

the "progress" variable is how i am updating my progress bar, with the backroundworker report progress (as you can see)

for each checkbox i have increased the progress variable by 3. so by time you get to the last checkbox progress = 100

this is great, but if the user only ticks the first three checkboxes, the progress bar will go from 0% to 3%, to 6% and then jump straight to 100% at the end which isn' great.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to make this a little bit more clever?

My first thought was to divide the amount of checkboxes ticked by 100, but then I wouldn't know how to update the progress bar with this data.

Comment: Why not you use a global counter like `counter += 3` when you check any checkbox.?

Answer (score 0):

```
Checkbox[] checkboxes;    

public void FormInitializationOrWhatever()
{
    Checkbox checkboxName1 = new CheckBox(), checkboxName2 = new CheckBox(), ...

    this.checkboxes = new CheckBox[] { checkboxName1, checkboxName2, ... };

    foreach (CheckBox cb in this.checkboxes)
    {
        cb.CheckedChanged += onSomeCheckboxWasClicked;
    }
}    

void onSomeCheckboxWasClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progress = (int)(((float)this.checkboxes.Count(cb => cb.Checked) / this.checkboxes.Length) * 100);
}
```

Basically, keep all the checkboxes in a collection and call a method that updates the progress each time a checkbox is updated. There are other ways to do this, I used an event-driven style.

progress = (int)(((float)this.checkboxes.Count(cb => cb.Checked) / this.checkboxes.Length) * 100);

should give you the percentage of the checkboxes that are checked compared to the total number of checkboxes, as an integer between 0 and 100.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** This answer provided by the OP, originally as part of his question. I have moved it here to be in line with site guidelines.

---

Thanks for your suggestions guys. I have come to a solution I'm happy with. Because I'm new to C# I've had to come up with a solution that I understand.

Basically, I created a collection, and then had if statements to add or remove a checkbox from the collection based on whether or not they are checked.

```
var cbs = new List<CheckBox>();


        if(imageinfo.Checked == true)
        {
            cbs.Add(imageinfo);
        }

        else
        {
            cbs.Remove(imageinfo);
        }
```

I then divided 100 by the collection count. and had this as a variable "interval"

```
int interval = 100 / cbs.Count;
```

I then had within each process

```
if (imageinfo.Checked == true)
        {

            progress = progress + interval;
            string commandlineargs = "-f " + imagefile + " imageinfo" + " --output-file=" + output + @"\imageinfo.txt";
            Process process = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = vollocation;
            startInfo.Arguments = commandlineargs;
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
            process.Close();

        }
```

progress = progress + interval. This meant that if I had 5 tick boxes ticked. the interval would be 20 and the progress bar goes up by 20 each time a ticked process is complete.

This is probably really dirty code, so I would still really appreciate suggestion on how it could be done better. But as you can see my knowledge is pretty basic so alot of things go straight over my head.